# Accessing a list value in a dictionary in a list in one line

Tags: python

I have a list which looks like this

```
Movies = ['Pulp Fiction', ['Cast Away', 'Tom Hanks'] , {9:'Kitaro Killman'} , {'Toy Story' : [1,2,3]}]
```

I want to access `2`, inside the `"Toy Story"` entry in a single line without mentioning `'Toy Story'` in my code. I tried using `.values()` and then indexing. It is saying indexing doesn't work under dictionary. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you looking for `Movies['Toy Story'][1]`?

Comment: No. Suppose I do not know 'Toy Story' is the value there.

Comment: So you're searching for a value of `2` inside a dict of lists?

Comment: My attempt was Movies[3].values()[1]

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes. But without mentioning `'Toy Story'` in the code.

Comment: Can you explain in English exactly what the logic is? "The 2nd entry in the 3rd list in the dictionary"? "The first value I find that's equal to 2 in any list in the dictionary"?

Comment: @Arun Please remember to make all description updates in your question.  We should not have to read all of the comments to know what you're asking, especially when the comment is to one of the answers.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Here I was trying to check whether we can access the list values within a dictionary without using the keyword. I was trying in different ways but wasn't been to able to solve. seyi and mklucz gave the answer correctly. I guess I was missing the [0] part.

Answer (score 1):

`Movies["Toy Story"][1]` should be sufficient.  `values` gets you a list of the values for all movies, in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> Movies = ['Pulp Fiction', ['Cast Away', 'Tom Hanks'] , {9:'Kitaro Killman'} , {'Toy Story' : [1,2,3]}]
>>> Movies[3]["Toy Story"][1]
2
```

I don't quite get what you're trying to do. Is this what you're after?

Comment: I do not want to mention `'Toy Story'` in the code.

Comment: How about `list(Movies[3].values())[0][1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
list(Movies[3].values())[0][1]
```

That should do it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but if it's access to the 2nd dictionary value then you have this
 
`Movies[3]["Toy Story"][1]`